# D3 Sunburst: Determine Leaf Color by Data and have its Parents Inherit that Color

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

So I am fairly new to D3 visualizations and have run into a roadblock in my learning.  I have a pretty basic sunburst set up running off data that determines if a test had a "Failure" or "Success".  This Failure or Success is represented as the outer ring of the sunburst as the data's Result.

I'm trying to change this outer ring's color based on this Success or Failure.  For example if the test result is Success, the color will be green and if a Failure it will turn red.  I feel like there is a way to do this that I'm just completely overlooking.

Also once that color has been determined, I want it's parent arcs, all the way to the innermost ring,  to "inherit" this color and red will have the higher priority. So basically if one group of test has a failure in it, that arc that represents that group will be red as well.

PRTG's sunburst works in this manner and I cant find the connection between the two to implement this functionality.

I'm using the basic sunburst code from D3's examples:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
var _ = require('underscore');
var SimpleSplunkView = require("splunkjs/mvc/simplesplunkview");  
var nester = require("../underscore-nest/underscore-nest");
var d3 = require("../d3/d3");

require("css!./sunburst.css");

window.nester = nester;
var ANIMATION_DURATION = 750;  // milliseconds

var Sunburst = SimpleSplunkView.extend({
    moduleId: module.id,

    className: "splunk-toolkit-sunburst", 

    options: {
        managerid: null,  
        data: 'preview', 
        chartTitle: null,
        valueField: null,
        categoryFields: null,
        truncateValue: 0,
        formatLabel: _.identity,
        formatTooltip: function(d) {
            return (d.name || "Total") + ": " + d.value;
        }
    },

    output_mode: "json_rows",

    initialize: function() {
        SimpleSplunkView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        this.settings.on("change:valueField", this.render, this);
        this.settings.on("change:categoryFields", this.render, this);
        this.settings.on("change:formatLabel change:formatTooltip change:chartTitle", this.render, this);

        // Set up resize callback. 
        $(window).resize(_.debounce(_.bind(this._handleResize, this), 20));
    },

    _handleResize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    createView: function() {
        // Here we wet up the initial view layout
        var margin = {top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30};
        var availableWidth = parseInt(this.settings.get("width") || this.$el.width());
        var availableHeight = parseInt(this.settings.get("height") || this.$el.height());

        this.$el.html("");

        var svg = d3.select(this.el)
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", availableWidth)
            .attr("height", availableHeight)
            .attr("pointer-events", "all");

        // The returned object gets passed to updateView as viz
        return { container: this.$el, svg: svg, margin: margin};
    },

    // making the data look how we want it to for updateView to do its job
    formatData: function(data) {
        var valueField = this.settings.get('valueField');
        var rawFields = this.resultsModel.data().fields;
        var fieldList = this.settings.get("categoryFields");
        if(fieldList){
            fieldList = fieldList.split(/[ ,]+/);
        }
        else{
            fieldList = this.resultsModel.data().fields;
        }
        var objects = _.map(data, function(row) {
            return _.object(rawFields, row);
        });
        var dataResults = nester.nest(objects, fieldList, function(children) {
            var total = 0;
            _.each(children, function(child){
                var size = child[valueField] || 1;
                total += size;
            });
            return total;
        });
        dataResults['name'] = this.settings.get("chartTitle") || "";
        data = {
            'results': dataResults,
            'fields': fieldList
        };
        return data;
    },

    updateView: function(viz, data) {
        var that = this;
        var formatLabel = this.settings.get("formatLabel") || _.identity;
        var formatTooltip = this.settings.get("formatTooltip") || function(d) { return d.name; };
        var truncateValue = this.settings.get("truncateValue");
        var containerHeight = this.$el.height();
        var containerWidth = this.$el.width(); 

        // Clear svg
        var svg = $(viz.svg[0]);
        svg.empty();
        svg.height(containerHeight);
        svg.width(containerWidth);

        // Add the graph group as a child of the main svg
        var graphWidth = containerWidth - viz.margin.left - viz.margin.right;
        var graphHeight = containerHeight - viz.margin.top - viz.margin.bottom;
        var graph = viz.svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("width", graphWidth)
            .attr("height", graphHeight)
            .attr("transform", "translate("  
                    + ((graphWidth/2) + viz.margin.left ) + ","  
                    + ((graphHeight/2) + viz.margin.top ) + ")");

        var radius = Math.min(graphWidth, graphHeight) / 2;

        var color = d3.scale.category20().range(["#98df8a"]);

        var colorA = d3.scale.category20().range(["#98df8a"]);  //green
        var colorB = d3.scale.category20().range(["#d62728"]);  //red
        var colorC = d3.scale.category20().range(["#bcbd22"]);  //yellow

        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([0, radius]);

        var partition = d3.layout.partition()
            .value(function(d) { return d['value']; });

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
            .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
            .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
            .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

        var root = data.results;

        var g = graph.selectAll("g")
            .data(partition.nodes(root))
            .enter().append("g");

        var leaves = d3.selectAll("rect").filter(function(d) {
            return d.children === null; });

        var path = g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) {return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
            .on("click", click);

        path.append("title")
            .text(formatTooltip);

        var textAnchorPos = function(depthMarker) {
            return function(d) {
                return (d.depth === depthMarker) ? 'middle' : ((x(d.x + d.dx / 2) > Math.PI) ? "end" : "start");
            };
        };

        var textTransform = function(depthMarker) { 
            return function(d) {
                // Objects at the origin don't need to be rotated
                var angle = x(d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI + (d.depth === depthMarker ? 0 : -90);
                // Objects at the origin don't need to be moved.
                // "5" pads the text off the drawn circle.
                var translation = d.depth === depthMarker ? 0 : (y(d.y) + 5);
                var rotate = angle;
                return "rotate(" + rotate + ")translate(" + (translation) + ")rotate(" + (angle > 90 ? -180 : 0) + ")";
            };
        };

        var text = g.append("text")
            .attr("text-anchor", textAnchorPos(0))
            .attr("transform", textTransform(0))
            .attr("dy", ".2em")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .text(function(d) {
                var sliceWidth = Math.abs(Math.max(0, y(d.y)) - Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)));
                var formatted = formatLabel(d.name);

                // Trunctate the title
                return formatted.substring(0, sliceWidth / truncateValue); 
            })
            .on("click", click);

        text.append("title")
            .text(formatTooltip);

        function click(d) {
            // The "at depth" object is treated differently;
            // centered and not rotated.
            var depthMarker = d.depth;
            // fade out all text elements
            text.transition().attr("opacity", 0);
            path.transition()
              .duration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
              .attrTween("d", arcTween(d))
              .each("end", function(e, i) {
                  // check if the animated element's data e lies
                  // within the visible angle span given in d and
                  // the element is d or a possible child of d
                  if ((e.x >= d.x && e.x < (d.x + d.dx)) && (e.depth >= d.depth)) { 
                    // get a selection of the associated text element
                    var arcText = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("text");
                    // fade in the text element and recalculate positions
                    arcText.transition().duration(ANIMATION_DURATION)
                        .attr("opacity", 1)
                        .attr("text-anchor", textAnchorPos(depthMarker))
                        .attr("transform", textTransform(depthMarker))
                        .attr("dy", ".2em")
                        .attr("x", 0);
                  }
              });
        }

        // Interpolate the scales!
        function arcTween(d) {
          var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
              yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
              yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
          return function(d, i) {
            return i
                ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
                : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
          };
        }
    }
});
return Sunburst;
```

});

Comment: Oh geez I didn't even see that, thank you for that edit!

Answer (score 1):

The coloring happens here:

```
var path = g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function(d) {return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
            .on("click", click);
```

So you might be able to examine the test-state of the element that get's passed to the anonymous function (in the *style* call) and return 'green' or 'red'. This might be quite straight forward for the leaves, but a little trickier for the parents. Since you must discover by looking at the parent element if it has any children with failed tests than return 'red', else return 'green'.